# Nuxt.js common SCSS modules?

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I have a `util.scss` file that I would like to include in several components:

```scss
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  ...
}
```

I import and use this file in my components like this:

```js
<template>
  <div :class="$style.grid"> ... </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" module>
@import 'util.scss';

...
</style>
```

This way the `util.scss` content will be imported for each component, resulting in many duplications in the final built bundle. Is there a way to import this file only once and reuse it for all components?

I know I could use the [css](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-css) property in `nuxt.config.js` to import the file globally as a normal stylesheet, but that does not allow it to be accessed using `$style.`

Comment: You could indeed set a `assets/scss/global.scss` file and set it up in `nuxt.config.js` with `css: ['~/assets/scss/global.scss'],`. Working great on my side. Do you really need to use `$style` in that case ? What will it bring more than a regular class already does ?

Comment: @kissu I will of course not get the obfuscation of classes with this approach, but I suppose that's what I have to do.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good way? I also need this, thanks.. :)

Comment: @Nadia, sadly not in the way I proposed in the original question. I try to instead of having large separate .scss files, to embed the style into Vue components and reuse those. If I still need to reuse some .scss files I just simply live with the overhead it introduces. For larger .scss files, I think it's better to use non-modules, as already commented above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [@nuxtjs/style-resources](https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module#readme) module.
It was implemented in the core before but has been separated in a specific module recently. (cf. [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#styleresources))

Simply link your css file in the nuxt config and it will automatically be imported in every css files / component style tags :)

```
// nuxt.config.js
styleResources: {
   scss: ['~/assets/scss/global.scss'],
}
```

Comment: This works fine for e.g. variables, but not for actual styles as seen in my example `util.scss` file. This would cause all the styles in `util.scss` to be included in **every** component, increasing the build size. This is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module#warning).

Comment: You're right, of course. And I don't know any way better that wouldn't result in css module duplications sadly...